# Calculating historic S&P 500 returns

Tags: stock-analysis, historical-data, rate-of-return, historical-analysis

I'm using the S&P 500 data provided by [Robert Shiller](http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data.htm) which goes back to 1871.

I've then calculated the percent return for each month, the simple arithmetic average is 0.43%.  Calculating the compound annual growth rate from 4.44 to 1550.83 over 1707 months results in 0.34%.

```
=(1550.83/4.44)^(1/(1707-1))-1
```

Both of these values are significantly below what I would expect of at least around 0.5%, which would be roughly 6% annually.

Am I doing a some calculations wrong?  Is this data not appropriate?  Is the notion of 6% long-term average for the stock market incorrect?

---

**Edit:** Another way from framing my question might be: how do I calculate the values shown at [MoneyChimp](http://www.moneychimp.com/features/market_cagr.htm) on my own?  I'm happy to use raw data other than the spreadsheet above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

6%? The S&P should be 10.6% average, and a CAGR of 8.92%.

I'm guessing the data you are studying doesn't include dividends, which, in my opinion, is what makes using the index number for certain purposes a bad starting point.

See the [Money Chimp site](http://www.moneychimp.com/features/market_cagr.htm) (bad name, great site) for the real numbers between any two years. MC uses the Shiller data as well, and sports a starting date of 1871. Welcome to Money.SE

EDIT - Dan and i exchanged emails. Shiller data is monthly, with the annual dividend number next to the S&P index for each month. One can take the Shiller data and manipulate to be a yearly series, or treat the dividend as 1/12 each month. Either way, the dividend should be taken into account.

Comment: I get a CAGR from 1871 to 2012 of 8.93. Chimp or I may have rounding issues, but nearly identical. I saw your email and replied.

Comment: @Dan If you are projecting forward, just make sure to factor in P/E trends and falling dividend ratios as well!